# NestJS. Can't inject a repository from a different module

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to use a *typeorm custom repository* defined in another module.

Following the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#typeorm-integration):

> If you want to use the repository outside of the module which imports TypeOrmModule.forFeature, you'll need to re-export the providers generated by it. You can do this by exporting the whole module, like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Role])],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule]
})
export class RoleModule {}
```

> Now if we import UsersModule in UserHttpModule, we can use @InjectRepository(User) in the providers of the latter module.

In my case i do:

```
@Module({
  imports: [RoleModule],
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Now when i inject the Role repository

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Role) private roleRepository: Repository<Role>) {}
}
```

i've got an error:
`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?).`

Is it me or is the documentation incorrect?
Can someone suggest what is the error here or give a corrected example?

Comment: I know you've already accepted an answer, but what was the full error you were getting?

Comment: `[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument RoleRepository at index [1] is available in the UserModule context.


Potential solutions:
- If RoleRepository is a provider, is it part of the current UserModule?
- If RoleRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing RoleRepository */ ]
  })`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Role])` to imports:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Role]), RoleModule], // <-- here
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: do we need to import RoleModule as well? If i omit RoleModule in import and only import `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Role])` it doesn't work?

Comment: Why do we have to import the entities again although we already import the whole module which contains the corresponding entity?